# Can I set a default page per area in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need a default page per area in .net core 2.2 (MVC). That means that if anyone types for example "https://url/admin" (where admin is the area), he is routed to say "https://url/admin/user/index". And I want to do that for every area.

Setting a second default page for area in app.UseMvc(routes =>... gave me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the default controller and action for area routing like

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        { 
            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "areas",
               template: "{area:exists}/{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Update:
If you would like to route different areas to different default page, you could set routing separately for the two areas:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapAreaRoute(
                name: "AdminRoute",
                areaName: "Admin",
                template: "Admin/{controller=News}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            routes.MapAreaRoute(
                name: "ManagementRoute",
                areaName: "Management",
                template: "Management/{controller=User}/{action=Detail}/{id?}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: This does not route the different areas to a default. I have the following: Area (Management, Admin), root Index. Management and Admin both have different controllers but I need to go to for example Admin/News/Index if someone types url/Admin and to Management/User/Detail if someone types url/Management.

Comment: I'm so embaressed. I had a typo in the route: Details. Should have been Detail... Blinded by code :s